# how to get the php variable without submitting form through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to AJAX

I want to do something like

```
$query="select name from login_master where name=txtName.value();";
//txtName is a name of textbox.
```

But without submitting the form.
can i do this with ajax?

Comment: You’ll need to explain your problem a little more and give some examples in order for us to better understand what you’re trying to do.

Comment: You can't pass the data without submitting the form. Could you please be more specific what you would like to achieve?

Comment: You could trap a click on the submit button and send the data from the form through ajax and return false, which in turn will stop the page from reloading.

Comment: Never ever put direct user input `txtName.value()` inside your query w/out checking it for possible injections first!

Comment: @y2ok I think he means how do you do AJAX, i.e. how do you pass data to the server in a POST/GET request without using forms.  I think he just worded it badly.

Comment: @JonTaylor , possible :). NiraliJoshi , check please Jon Taylor answer ;)

Comment: simply i want to check that is there any value in table which matches with textbox value.but withot clicking the submit button.

Comment: Well what event do you want to do it on? It cant magically read your mind and decide when to check, if not on a click then possibly on a loss of focus on the text box? Or potentially a key up?

Answer (score 1):

In AJAX you will make a call to whatever PHP page it is that contains this query.  Your php page will carry out the query and echo out the results in a form your Javascript can understand, possibly either HTML or JSON.

In the success handler of your ajax call you can then handle the returned data.

Also on the server side be careful because anything input by the user can be potentially hazardous.  Use prepared statements with mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type:'POST',  //POST or GET depending if you want to use _GET or _POST in php
       url:'your-page.php', //Effectively the form action, where it goes to.
       data:$('#txtName').val(),  //The data to send to the page (Also look up form serialise)
       success:function(e) {
            // On success this fill fire, depends on the return you will use in your page.
       }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
</script>


<form>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then in your `your-page.php` or whatever you will call it you will pickup the `$_POST['txtName']` and query your database.

Comment: eughh why does everyone just write the code out for them?  Its clear they need a bit of help but writing the answer out in full is never going to help them learn as they will just copy/paste.  Then they will be back again undoubtedly with more basic questions next time they need to make an ajax call.  It's far better to give them pointers and an understanding of what they need to do in order to achieve their goal and actually let them figure out the code themselves.

Comment: also your code will not work as you are looking for an input with id `txtName` except you have given it a name. And pretty sure your data section is wrong. You should be doing something like `data: {txtName: value here}`  where value here should be replaced by the value fo the text input.

Comment: I just said, "something like this should work", he still needs to do some research of his own. It was more like a hint=)

Comment: Its not a hint, thats a full solution. If you give a solution you really should make sure you get it right, especially for someone who obviously is new to coding.  Your syntax errors will undoubtedly confuse him more.

Comment: I never said it was a full solution. He was asking if there was a way to send data without submitting the form, which the above code should do?

Comment: This is a full solution as he has a form with a txtName variable he needs to pass to his PHP page, what else is there to do apart from the code you've written? Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.  Not much.  And as I mentioned giving examples that still after your edit has syntax errors is just going to confuse him more.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I added comments to your posts code, that way they may be able to work through and learn ajax/jQ. Also I suggest the OP looks at : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for help on this